# Riemann integration and equality ae

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f,g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable functions such that $f = g$ a.e. (with respect to Lebesgue outer measure). Then how would one show that $\int f = \int g$ as *Riemann integrals*? For Lebesgue integrals it's clear enough, but I don't know how to procede for Riemann integrals.

I suppose it would be helpful to first show that if some function $h$ is Riemann integrable and $h=0$ a.e. then the Riemann integral $\int h = 0$. But I don't know how to show that.

Edit: Assume that we don't know anything about Lebesgue integration at this point.

Comment: Not knowing Lebesgue integral, but knowing "measure zero".  Yes, it should be possible.  Work on the difference $h=f-g$, show that if a Riemann-integrable function $h$ vanishes except on a set of "measure zero", then its Riemann integral is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $h$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and vanishes except on a set of measure zero.  Consider any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$.  Then the upper sum $U(h,P)$ is $\ge 0$, because no interval of $P$ has measure zero.  Similarly the lower sum $L(h,P)$ is $\le 0$.  By Riemann-integrability, the Riemann integral is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $h$ is Riemann integrable it is Lebesgue integrable, and the two integrals agree. But if $h=0$ a.e. (with respect to Lebsgue measure) then it's Lebesgue integral is $0$. Since the Riemann integral equals the Lebesgue integral, the Riemann integral is also $0$.

Comment: Lets assume that we don't know the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Wow, OK... Fair enough! Maybe the result that Riemann integrable implies continuous except on a set of null Lebsgue measure will help?